# Change DocumentRoot in 16.04

Tags: permissions, apache2

I've read quite a few posts on how to change apache2 DocumentRoot on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's what I did:

1. Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to show:

   ```
   <Directory /media/werner/EDrive/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to show:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /media/werner/EDrive/www/html

   <Directory "/media/werner/EDrive/www/html">
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` to show:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /media/werner/EDrive/www/html
   ```
4. Restart apache2.

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

   Now if I go to localhost, I get a 403 Forbidden error.
5. Permissions of `/media/werner/EDrive/www/html`:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x 30 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 29 13:09 html/
   ```

What to do? In my mind, I am pointing at the right directory, but there seems to be a permissions issue!? My user (werner) is a member of the www-data group.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. The ROOT of my new directory (i.e /media in my case) must be owned by www-data

So

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media
```

did the trick for me

Comment: This is too broad, since you're saying that every single drive someone might insert needs to be owned by `www-data` in order for something in a subdirectory of only one of the inserted drives to work properly. **This can greatly damage the permissions of any other inserted drives.** It's very likely that something much more limited like `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/werner/EDrive/www` or `/media/werner/EDrive` would have worked.